# JavaScript heap out of memory in Angular 7 using Azure DevOps

Tags: angular, npm, azure-devops, angular7

I am getting **FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory** after Angular 7.1 upgrade. The previous version 6.1 was working perfectly fine.

I get the error only in Azure DevOps while running `ng build --prod` command. It builds perfectly fine in local.

Below are the detail logs. Any idea why I am getting this error?

```
2018-11-22T06:40:36.2804965Z ##[section]Starting: npm build
2018-11-22T06:40:36.2809301Z ==============================================================================
2018-11-22T06:40:36.2809365Z Task         : npm
2018-11-22T06:40:36.2809456Z Description  : Install and publish npm packages, or run an npm command. Supports npmjs.com and authenticated registries like Package Management.
2018-11-22T06:40:36.2809496Z Version      : 1.0.27
2018-11-22T06:40:36.2809531Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-11-22T06:40:36.2809612Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613746)
2018-11-22T06:40:36.2809648Z ==============================================================================
2018-11-22T06:40:36.7158800Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2018-11-22T06:40:36.8019327Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2018-11-22T06:40:36.8872807Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" --version"
2018-11-22T06:40:37.5174051Z 6.4.1
2018-11-22T06:40:38.9461529Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" config list"
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5927698Z ; cli configs
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5928553Z metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5929006Z scope = ""
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5929176Z user-agent = "npm/6.4.1 node/v8.12.0 win32 x64"
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5929292Z 
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5929425Z ; environment configs
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5929577Z cache = "C:\\npm\\cache"
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5929756Z prefix = "C:\\npm\\prefix"
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5929899Z userconfig = "D:\\a\\1\\npm\\17729.npmrc"
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5930010Z 
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5930159Z ; builtin config undefined
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5930270Z 
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5930403Z ; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5930552Z ; cwd = D:\a\1\s\client
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5930686Z ; HOME = C:\Users\VssAdministrator
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5930817Z ; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5930928Z 
2018-11-22T06:40:39.5931996Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" run build"
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0639548Z FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0640628Z  1: node_module_register
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0640676Z  2: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0640710Z  3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0640744Z  4: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0640825Z  5: v8::internal::Smi::SmiPrint
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0640861Z  6: v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0640894Z  7: v8::internal::AsmJsScanner::IsNumberStart
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0640967Z  8: 000002B496D043C1
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0641001Z npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0641034Z npm ERR! errno 3
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0641210Z npm ERR! iceux@0.0.1 build: `ng build --prod`
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0641470Z npm ERR! Exit status 3
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0641528Z npm ERR! 
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0641569Z npm ERR! Failed at the iceux@0.0.1 build script.
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0641615Z npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0641703Z 
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0641749Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0641795Z npm ERR!     C:\npm\cache\_logs\2018-11-22T07_33_30_018Z-debug.log
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0641823Z 
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0641910Z > iceux@0.0.1 build D:\a\1\s\client
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0641951Z > ng build --prod
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0641978Z 
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1213960Z Found npm debug log, make sure the path matches with the one in npm's output: C:\npm\cache\_logs\2018-11-22T07_33_30_018Z-debug.log
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1214046Z 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1214104Z 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1214189Z 1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1215590Z 1 verbose cli   'run',
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1215635Z 1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1215667Z 2 info using npm@6.4.1
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1215727Z 3 info using node@v8.12.0
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1215759Z 4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1215801Z 5 info lifecycle iceux@0.0.1~prebuild: iceux@0.0.1
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1215835Z 6 info lifecycle iceux@0.0.1~build: iceux@0.0.1
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1216048Z 7 verbose lifecycle iceux@0.0.1~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1216372Z 8 verbose lifecycle iceux@0.0.1~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\a\1\s\client\node_modules\.bin;C:\agents\2.141.1\externals\git\cmd;C:\tools\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\mysql-5.7.21-winx64\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\npm\prefix;C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Ruby\2.5.0\x64\bin;C:\Go1.11\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\ServiceFabricLocalClusterManager;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1216877Z 9 verbose lifecycle iceux@0.0.1~build: CWD: D:\a\1\s\client
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1216979Z 10 silly lifecycle iceux@0.0.1~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ng build --prod' ]
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217028Z 11 silly lifecycle iceux@0.0.1~build: Returned: code: 3  signal: null
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217062Z 12 info lifecycle iceux@0.0.1~build: Failed to exec build script
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217103Z 13 verbose stack Error: iceux@0.0.1 build: `ng build --prod`
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217135Z 13 verbose stack Exit status 3
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217173Z 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217215Z 13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217250Z 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217287Z 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217332Z 13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217381Z 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217413Z 13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217448Z 13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217488Z 14 verbose pkgid iceux@0.0.1
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217521Z 15 verbose cwd D:\a\1\s\client
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217551Z 16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217588Z 17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217629Z 18 verbose node v8.12.0
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217659Z 19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217690Z 20 error code ELIFECYCLE
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1217727Z 21 error errno 3
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1218070Z 22 error iceux@0.0.1 build: `ng build --prod`
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1218102Z 22 error Exit status 3
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1218134Z 23 error Failed at the iceux@0.0.1 build script.
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1218187Z 23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1218220Z 24 verbose exit [ 3, true ]
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1218241Z 
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1286371Z ##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 3
2018-11-22T07:33:30.1298403Z ##[section]Finishing: npm build
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "iceux",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --ssl true",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "testauto": "ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint iceux --format stylish",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "ng e2e --dev-server-target=iceux:serve",
    "e2e:fast": "ng e2e --configuration=fast",
    "e2e:azure": "ng e2e --configuration=azure",
    "e2e:perf": "ng e2e --configuration=perf"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "7.1.0",
    "@epicor/kinetic": "^2.1.0-alpha.20",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^6.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^3.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.4.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^3.1.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-menu": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar": "^0.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^2.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "latest",
    "@telerik/kendo-intl": "^1.4.4",
    "angular2-query-builder": "^0.3.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "json-logic-js": "^1.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "logrocket": "^0.6.17",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular/cli": "7.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.1.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.108",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.3.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.5",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Also the webpack and it's config file. What is the version of Webpack and middleware ?

Comment: Can you share the package.json file ? I was also facing the same issue, I have resolved it yesterday

Comment: I have added package.json file. I am not using any extra webpack configuration, apart from what Angular uses.

Comment: Why 8gb are required to build a simple angular app?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try to run prod build like this:

```
node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

I have the same error yesterday and it's helps me to avoid it.

Comment: yes ...that's the answer . it's suddenly happening since last few days in pipeline

Comment: However in my case  `--max_old_space_size=4096` worked

Comment: After using --max_old_space_size=5048, it didn't showed any aot build errors. It builds as a normal JIT complier and emitted dist folder having huge main.chunk.js.

Comment: @Arron try to add this params to build function --aot --build-optimizer

Comment: I used the following command,
"prod": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer=false --verbose=true". but no use.

Comment: @Arron why did you disable build optimizer ?

Comment: @Arron Total bundle sizes with Build Optimizer are smaller if there is no separate vendor chunk because having vendor code in the same chunk as app code makes it possible for Uglify to remove more unused code.

Comment: @iliya.rudberg Thank you! The build command provided in the answer solved my build issues.

Comment: Increasing heap limit is not a solution. It's just a patch. I need a solution that can reduce memory uses. I debugged angular7 application with the help of siege and node inspector seems every time angular objects and arrays are pushing into memory without releasing memory.

Comment: @KrrishYadav in some applications increasing of heap limit is the only solution. About your issue: try to null variables on destroy of your component. May help

Comment: @iliya.rudberg As we know js is using garbage collector by default. We don't need to release memory manually. and setting all variables in destroy null cant be good for a big application.

Comment: @KrrishYadav you need to read how garbage collector is work's - https://javascript.info/garbage-collection

Comment: @KrrishYadav if your component will not properly destroyed, garbage collector will not work's.

Comment: When I am trying this inside docker image, it's not working.

Comment: @Manwal question was about prod bundle which usually run outside docker container. This article may help you in your case - https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/node-js-memory-management-in-container-environments-7eb8409a74e8

Answer (score 7):

On Mac you can run `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192` in the terminal to fix future NPM functions.

Answer (score 7):

Temporary solution to fix JavaScript heap memory issues are

```
ng node --max_old_space_size=4096 && ng build --prod
```

You can add more space as well

```
ng node --max_old_space_size=8192 && ng build --prod
```

Or disable AOT itself

```
ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false
```

If you have problem with running the application using ng serve itself then use below command

```
node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve
```

But my suggestion is to cross check your application design and verify all module import, external libraries are imported correctly. make sure there is no duplicate imports. Use shared module for all reusable components etc 
[More info](https://www.angulartutorial.net/2020/02/how-to-solve-javascript-heap-out-of.html)

Answer (score 4):

I am bit late to answer but I have working solution for both Linux and Mac

To fix it permanently you should edit the .zshrc file in your home folder and write this in the bottom

`export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192`

To fix in Linux you can edit .bashrc in your home folder and write in the bottom

`export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192`

Note: Considering your computer has 8GB (8192MB) memory installed, if you have more or less then adjust the value accordingly

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using angular CLI, You can use this command:

```
 NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096" ng serve
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using the standard angular cli toolchain (`npm` and `ng`), there's a slick way to control `max_old_space_size` for all of your `ng` commands. Add to your `package.json` scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "node --max_old_space_size=10000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng",
...
  }
```

Then from the command line you can use this modified version of `ng` (don't forget the `--` between 'run' and 'ng':

```
npm run -- ng build --prod
```

It's really nice if you ever decide you need to change the heap size, you only need to change it one place in `package.json`. All your command-line usage stays the same.

(I also prefer this method because it ensures that the `ng` invoked is the local version specified by your project, not the global installation which may not match.)

Comment: Is this going to run with angular 7(and node 14)?

Answer (score 1):

Fast forward to 2023, my solution is using correct Node.js.

For using an old project, I reinstall an 32-bit(x86) Node.js, this leads to 'JavaScript heap out of memory', and I can't set `--max-old-space-size>4000` maybe because of x86 Node.js limit.

Finally, I install nvm(https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases), and latest version x64 Node.js solved my problem. And nvm helps me switch easily between two version of node.js.

Answer (score 0):

May be late to this. Just update your Node to latest version. Mostly issue with few of releases V 10

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue for Angular 8 && Gradle build in Jenkins. I tried updating --max_old_space_size and NODE_OPTIONS but it still not working.

I ended up adding gradle.properties file and update the JVM size like this:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](https://dev.to/andreisfedotov/fix-of-angular-cli-javascript-heap-out-of-memory-error-while-running-ng-serve--1jjh)
The quick and effective solution for Windows

1. Open `C:\Users\userName\%AppData%\Roaming\npm`
2. Copy/paste the following code into `ng.cmd`:

```
    @IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
     "%~dp0\node.exe" --max_old_space_size=8048 "%~dp0\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng" 
    %* 
    ) ELSE (
    @SETLOCAL 
    @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;% 
    node --max_old_space_size=8048 "%~dp0\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %* 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

just complementing the previous answers, you can set a bigger space size on your package.json like this:

```
"scripts": {
   ...
   "start": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
   ...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, if dependencies are not loaded prior to the build, this error will occur. Retry building after loading the dependencies.

1. `npm install`
2. `ng build --prod`

Answer (score 0):

Set environment then run command (Working for Windows):

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 && ng build
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was fixed by removing `.angular` folder.

It's a temporary files directory generated on `ng serve`.

Answer (score -3):

Try to run prod build like this:

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 "node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng" build --configuration=production
```