# JavaScript heap out of memory in Angular 11 project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have upgraded my project from angular 7 to angular 11 with the node version of 14.16.0 LTS.
But After the upgrade when I have uploaded it to the UAT server, it's working perfectly. But whenever I am uploading this project into the LIVE server, After sometimes it's got stuck on the site and showing us an error 502 Bad request and in the server console, it's showing us that

Error in Server Console:

```
<--- JS stacktrace --->
frontend_1  |
frontend_1  | ==== JS stack trace =========================================
frontend_1  |
frontend_1  |     0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x558257165c59]
frontend_1  |     1: StubFrame [pc: 0x5582570e799b]
frontend_1  | Security context: 0x3fd4348808a1 <JSObject>
frontend_1  |     2: debugCheckDirectivesFn(aka debugCheckDirectivesFn) [0x16c8a5483a69] 
[/home/myapp/frontend/dist/server.js:~552655] [pc=0xe21d88c8296](this=0x33c0984004a9 
<undefined>,0x2737fd17c6a9 <Object map = 0x387bbf7c5a21>,111,0)
frontend_1  |     3: arguments adaptor frame: 4->3
frontend_1  |     4: /* anonymous */ [0x8dec769c961] [/home/leaset...
frontend_1  | **FATAL ERROR: **Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - 
JavaScript heap out of memory****
frontend_1  |
frontend_1  |
frontend_1  | Writing Node.js report to file: report.20210219.183001.1.0.001.json
frontend_1  | Node.js report completed
```

I have implemented all things which are available in the StackOverflow Q&A section, i.e [JavaScript heap out of memory in Angular 7 using Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435533/javascript-heap-out-of-memory-in-angular-7-using-azure-devops). I have increased the memory of node old max size, but nothing happened.

So, I am attaching the `package.json` code.

```
{
    "name": "myapp",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {"ng": "ng","start": "ng serve","test": "ng test","lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts - 
    t verbose","e2e": "ng e2e","build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run 
    webpack:server","serve:ssr": "node dist/server.js","build:client-and-server-bundles": "node 
    - 
    - 
    max_old_space_size=16384 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod  --stats-json -- 
    source- 
    map=false  --build-optimizer --aot && ng run myapp:server","webpack:server": "webpack -- 
    config 
    webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors","build:stats": "ng build --stats- 
    json","bundle- 
    report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/browser/stats.json"
    },
    "dependencies": {"@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^2.0.3","@angular/animations": 
    "^11.0.2","@angular/cdk": "^11.0.1","@angular/common": "^11.0.2","@angular/compiler": 
    "^11.0.2","@angular/core": "^11.0.2","@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0- 
    beta.33","@angular/forms": 
    "^11.0.2","@angular/http": "^7.2.16","@angular/material": "^11.0.1","@angular/platform- 
    browser": 
    "^11.0.2","@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.2","@angular/platform-server": 
    "^11.0.2","@angular/router": "^11.0.2","@kolkov/ngx-gallery": "^1.2.3","@ng-bootstrap/ng- 
    bootstrap": "^4.2.2","@ng-plus/signature-pad": "^1.0.7","@ng-toolkit/universal": 
    "^8.1.0","@ngu/carousel": "^3.0.1","@nguniversal/express-engine": 
    "^11.0.0","@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^9.0.0-next.9","@schematics/angular": 
    "^11.0.2","@schematics/update": "^0.1100.2","@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36","angular2- 
    signaturepad": "^2.11.0","angular4-social-login": "^1.1.1","angularx-social-login": 
    "^3.5.1","aws-sdk": "^2.800.0","compression": "^1.7.4","cookieconsent": "^3.1.1","core-js": 
    "^2.6.12","cors": "^2.8.5","doorgets-ng-truncate": "^2.0.2","express": "^4.17.1","file- 
    saver": 
    "^2.0.5","googleapis": "^52.1.0","hammer": "0.0.5","hammerjs": "^2.0.8","localstorage- 
    polyfill": 
    "^1.0.1","method-override": "^3.0.0","moment": "^2.29.1","morgan": "^1.10.0","ng-bootstrap": 
    "^1.6.3","ng-circle-progress": "^1.6.0","ng-click-outside": "^7.0.1","ng-lazyload-image": 
    "^5.1.2","ng2-adsense": "^9.1.0","ng2-charts": "^2.4.2","ng2-charts-x": "^2.0.6","ng5- 
    slider": 
    "^1.2.6","ngx-cookie": "^4.1.2","ngx-cookieconsent": "^2.2.3","ngx-facebook": "^3.0.0- 
    0","ngx- 
    gallery-9": "^1.0.6","ngx-image-compress": "^8.0.4","ngx-image-cropper": "^1.5.1","ngx- 
    infinite- 
    scroll": "^7.0.1","ngx-json-ld": "^0.3.1","ngx-mask": "^7.8.9","ngx-metafrenzy": 
    "^3.2.0","ngx- 
    perfect-scrollbar": "^7.2.1","ngx-signaturepad": "0.0.9","node-fetch": "^2.6.0","pubnub": 
    "^4.29.10","pubnub-angular2": "^1.3.2","rxjs": "^6.6.3","rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3","s3fs": 
    "^2.5.0","ts-loader": "^5.3.3","tslib": "^1.14.1","webpack-cli": "^3.3.12","xmlbuilder": 
    "^13.0.1","zone.js": "^0.10.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.2","@angular-devkit/core": 
    "^11.0.2","@angular-devkit/schematics": "^11.0.2","@angular/cli": 
    "^11.0.2","@angular/compiler- 
    cli": "^11.0.2","@angular/language-service": "^11.0.2","@types/express": 
    "^4.17.9","@types/jasmine": "^3.6.2","@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8","@types/node": 
    "^11.15.39","@types/node-fetch": "^2.5.7","codelyzer": "^4.5.0","install": 
    "^0.13.0","jasmine- 
    core": "^3.6.0","jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1","karma": "^4.4.1","karma-chrome-launcher": 
    "^2.2.0","karma-cli": "^2.0.0","karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1","karma-jasmine": 
    "^2.0.1","karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4","protractor": "^5.4.4","rxjs-tslint": 
    "^0.1.8","ts-node": "~4.1.0","tslint": "^5.13.0","typescript": "~4.0.5","webpack-bundle- 
    analyzer": "^3.9.0","webpack-filter-warnings-plugin": "^1.2.1"}
}
```