# Angular 12 Throwing this error FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I updated my angular application version from angular 8 to 12, In previous version when I hit ng server my application server properly without through an any error but after update it to V12 it through me an error when I run by

1. ng serve
2. node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve

Above commands also not works and it show me error

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This error seems to be related to the generation of `sourceMaps`. Here is the issue on [Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21041?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container).

You can try disabling the generation of `sourceMaps` in `angular.json` as a workaround until the issue is resolved:

```
"sourceMap": false
```

Comment: just for a follow up my configuration in angular.json was like:
            "sourceMap": {
              "scripts": true,
              "styles": true,
              "vendor": true
            }
by changing styles and vendor to false I got past this error.

Comment: @jay-culpepper, that didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

I had this thing, than I changed my scripts to this:

```
 "start": "node --max_old_space_size=2192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
 "build": "node --max_old_space_size=2192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration production --build-optimizer=false --output-hashing=all",
```

but for building problem didn't dissapear, so I updated node to version 16, and now it's working

Answer (score -1):

This might have occurred as a result of dependencies not being loaded prior to the build. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74303590/7417998) for the solution.