# Angular: FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed — process out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I add one package in my angular project and in my other pc I have this error:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
2018-11-22T07:33:30.0640628Z  1: node_module_register
```

I try a lot things to solve this problem like
use increase-memory-limit npm 
use env variables, etc...

someone can help please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435533/javascript-heap-out-of-memory-in-angular-7-using-azure-devops

Comment: None of these resolutions work, so I opened another one.